# Django: Advanced Template Filters

Tags: python, django

Here's my problem,

In view I have,

```
object = Data.objects.all()
```

In template,

```
{% for obj in object %}

Here I can print Data...
But also I want to print Game and Extras. Where Game to related to "Data" through foreign 
key & "Extras" is related to "Game" through foreign key. This is how I'm doing it,

{% for abc in obj.game_set.all %}

Here I can print ]Games related to Data.
but also I want to print Extras. this is what I'm doing,

{% for var in abc.extras_set.all %}
{{ var }}

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Everything is fine accepted the fact that I want to print out latest 2 games having extras.

I can use distortreversed & then slice to get latest 2 games but that will simply print out the latest 2 games not will not give the latest 2 games having extras. SO, how can I do that?

Is there a way to do this filtering in view & then follow with for loop in the template?

Comment: Try constructing a `dict` and then pass it around the way you like, Django template can easily iterate dicts and accessing attributes is possible via `.` operator.

Comment: @nehemiah Sir, but how in this example?